# Choice Problem of (p,d,q) order for ARIMA

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I have two questions about selecting ARIMA order(p,d,q).

Assuming that ACF or PACF graph shows spike at lag 4 only
 (and there is no spike in any lags),

my question is,

1. Do I have to consider MA process rather than AR?
   (because there is no spike from lag 1 to lag n-1 sequently, in this case n equal to 4)

   What means such type of spike and which order(p,d,q) is considered?
2. Assuming that spike is shown at lag 4 in ACF,
   Can I make ARIMA model as order (0,0,4)

   not
   Y(t)= C - E(t) - aE(t-1)-bE(t-2)-cE(t-3)-dE(t-4)

   but
   Y(t)= C - E(t)- aE(t-4), where C is constant, a/b/c/d is coffiecients, E is error.

   If it is possible, 
   How can I make such model in R ?

Comment: Since you're using R, why not just use auto.arima() from the forecast package which will do the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

If the spike is in the pacf and pacf(4) is absolutely greater than .5 , you would prefer an AR representation of the form y(t)-phi1*y(t-4)=a(t) due to invertability restrictions otherwise an ma model would probably be adequate.

If your data is quarterly this can be accomplished with (0,0,0)(1,0,0) in terms of pdq PDQ

Alternatively you might use software that allows you to constrain a p=4 model with three coefficients being absent.

From your description , I would think that you may have some deterministic structure present like a first quarter effect rather than an auto-regressive structure.

Answer (score -2):

ans for Q1; in this case you have to consider both AR and MA terms and your final model would be ARIMA(4,0,4)

ans for Q2; go for MA model with forth MA term only (the second choice)

no idea about R